# Angular2 undefined DomSanitizer within Pipe

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm trying to use DomSanitizer to make my URL safe. I've followed [these steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JeKfQ2r2r8) as you can see below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
   name: 'youtube',
})
export class YoutubePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    transform(value: string, ...args) {
       value = value.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/');
       console.log(value);
       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    }
}
```

That logged value is ok, but I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' of undefined
```

which means to me that my object is not getting all set. I've already checked that 'constructor' is being called, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Try logging `this` and `this.sanitizer` to the console to see what you get.